# Setting Range for jQuery UI Sliders Based on Results of SQL Query

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, filtering

If you have a narrow results filter page with jquery ui range sliders which post data to a php page that is then output into a  on the same page, is there a way to generate the range values assigned to the jquery ui slider?

Something placed here I would imagine.. but don't know how to grab from the page that is doing the query/serving the results.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 50000,
        values: [ 0, 50000 ],
             });
          }
```

Comment: I don't understand, why you need the range? You can get the slider's value with jQuery and then make an ajax call that pass these values to a php script to handle them. But I think I'm missing something from the question

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you are asking, but if you need to set the range values programmatically based on a server response, then when you get the data from the server, you can get/set the values using the jQuery UI getter/setter.

The following shows the example of getting/setting the range, values, and value

```
//getter
var range = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "range" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "range", 'min' );

//getter
var values = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "values" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "values", [1,5,9] );

//getter
var value = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value", 37 );
```

Good Luck